# Tomcat - Image not display

Tags: java, tomcat

I am having problem with the tomcat deployment.

When I try to type

http://localhost:8080/contextpath

The image of my login page not display at all.

However, when I put the whole URL

http://localhost:8080/contextpath/Login/login.jsp

The image of my login page able to show.

### Solved

Did have this part in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/Login/login.jsp</welcome-file>
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with this information? Press F12 in your browser, open network panel, reload the page.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please show us your java code, `web.xml` , ...

Comment: In browser, press F12 (Google Chrome), check broken images. Change image path to path what use `requestContextPath`.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by including the request.getContextPath() into the coding. thanks all for your kind responses. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Susanto Please write your own Answer to your Question, and then mark it as accepted. Doing so flags this Question as having been resolved, and makes your solution clear to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code

before part image put artifactId

you can see artifactId in pom.xml

example

```
<img src="/retrytoolweb/logo/LOGOTL-8.svg" width="96" />
```

Hope to help.